# Restrict editing in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I was just wondering if there is a way that we disable editing of a specific word in the System.Window.Controls.RichTextBox? For example, I have "Hello This is a test", and I want to disable users to a edit test(which can be anything). I want to them to change whatever they want, but when they want to click or do anything on "test", it's somehow in a different color like gray(which is easy to do), but not editable.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality like this built into the RichTextBox. Your best bet is to create a custom control of some type or inherit from the RichTextBox and override methods to add your own functionality.

Comment: and the tricky part is at they type and change words, you have to keep range of every single word to keep the same decoration and restrictions.